# Why does the non-pointer std::any_cast not return a reference?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, stdany

The [`any_cast()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) function - say, for a non-const reference operand - has the following signature:

```
template<class T>
T any_cast(any& operand);
```

Why does this function not return a `T&` - where the documentation says the returned value is merely

```
static_cast<T>(*std::any_cast<U>(&operand))
```

?

Comment: If you want a ref, cant you just do `T& val = any_cast<T&>(any);`? Seems to me if you ask for a T, you should get a T (and not a T&).

Comment: There are things in C++ which you _cant_ create a reference to, and returning a reference to T would forbid those types in an any. Although they may be forbidden already.

Comment: For instance http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html

Comment: @MikeVine: Would `any_cast<T&>` even work? I know `any_cast` is very very sensitive. Also, if I can get an address - I can get a reference.